# Detecting remote files in Java

Tags: java, nio, nfs, inotify

I'm using Watcher in JDK7 which relies on inotify events. If the file is on a NFS, I want my program to fallback and use polling instead. Is there a way to detect if a file is on a remote drive (other than using Runtime.exec and parsing the mount table)? I'm only concerned with Linux compatibility for now.

I suppose one option is to use both inotify and polling when the program starts, but then disable the polling thread if an inotify event for my file is created.

Comment: You can try inotify and update your file programmatically. If you receive event, then you are good, if not - switch to polling.

Comment: java.nio.file.WatchService documentation implies that the watch service implementation will fallback to polling if there is no better mechanism to use in a particular case. It is possible that it will work for NFS file system too out of the box and you will not have to implement the polling yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get relatively reliable info about the underlying file system type with [FileStore.type()](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/FileStore.html#type%28%29).

It will definitely tell you if it's an NFS, or CIFS, not sure about other network mount types.

However I have no info about how reliable it is, @hoaz's suggestion to check if events are coming through might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have solved it by creating a new thread in de main class and touching the files periodically so a new change event gets fired.

The sample polls the dir for every 10 seconds does a touch.

Here a sample of the code:

```
package com.ardevco.files;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Touch implements Runnable {

    private Path touchPath;

    public Touch(Path touchPath) {
        this.touchPath = touchPath;
        this.checkPath = checkPath;

    }

    public static void touch(Path file) throws IOException {
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        touch(file, timestamp);
    }

    public static void touch(Path file, long timestamp) throws IOException {
        if (Files.exists(file)) {
            FileTime ft = FileTime.fromMillis(timestamp);
            Files.setLastModifiedTime(file, ft);
        }
    }

    List<Path> listFiles(Path path) throws IOException {
        final List<Path> files = new ArrayList<>();
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
            for (Path entry : stream) {
                if (Files.isDirectory(entry)) {
                    files.addAll(listFiles(entry));
                }
                files.add(entry);
            }
        }
        return files;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                for (Path path : listFiles(touchPath)) {
                    touch(path);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
            }
        }

    }

}
```